# To view folders of the file system from browser in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, filesystems, directory

I would like to have a link in my browser which when clicked opens a folder in the file system. I don't want it to get downloaded but only to be viewed. Is this possible in Ruby? What command can be used? Help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You can use the [`Dir` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html) to get the contents of a directory (emphasis mine):

> Objects of class `Dir` are directory streams representing directories in the underlying file system. They provide a variety of ways to **list directories and their contents**. See also `File`.

and then the usual Rails mechanisms to display that data to the user.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I'm new to RoR

Answer (score 0):

If you mean on the server and not on the user's computer:

```
Dir.foreach("/path/to/directory") { |file|
  puts file
}
```

You can do the same thing with `Dir#glob` too, except it will also take a wildcard pattern:

```
Dir.glob("/path/to/directory/*") { |file|
  puts file
}
```

Obviously `puts` won't cut it in Rails, but you get the idea.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I'm new to RoR.

Comment: When you output something in Rails, you do that by using a template file (or by manually sending some other response).  Using `puts`, just prints the output to the console rather than sending it to the browser (in contrast to what PHP does). You'll have to start by reading the Rails Guide since there is some basic MVC stuff you absolutely have to understand before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can simply insert a link to your local file system. For example,

```
<a href="/home/user/foo">open foo</a>
```

gives a link to `/home/user/foo` on your computer.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will help you :-

https://richonrails.com/articles/basic-file-and-directory-operations-in-ruby

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby-for-newbies-working-with-directories-and-files--net-18810